# Search for a string in a file and read the line after string match

Tags: ruby

I would like to look for a string in a file and output the rest of the line after this string - but without newline etc.

[File content]

```
 [Test]
 key1 = value
 key2 = value2

 [Test2]
 key1 = value3
 key3 = value4 value5
```

For example, I would like to read "value" when I search for Key1 in the Test section. When I search for key3 in the section Test2 I would like to get "value4 value5" as string.

My current approach is:

```
section = Test
key = key1

text = File.read(path)

# read complete section in value
sect_value = text.scan(/^[section]=(.+)$/).flatten.first

# read specific key from section
value = sect_value.scan(/^key =(.+)$/)
```

Is there a configparser which is already installed by the ruby package (without adding further gems)?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please show the code

Comment: I added my current approach, but I`m not really familiar with regex expressions.

Comment: Are you in control over the file structure? Can't you use YAML or JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in control of the file. The file ist created by a python program. There is no configparser in the default ruby engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first construct a file.

```
FNAME = 't'

File.write(FNAME, <<~END
cat
[Test]
 key1 = value
 key2 = value2

[Test2]
 key1 = value3
 key3 = value4 value5
dog
END
)
  #=> 90
```

The following method could be used to extract the values of interest.

```
def extract(section, key)
  rkey_match = /\A *#{key} *= /
  rkey_get   = /\A *#{key} *= *\K.*/
  section_found = false
  File.foreach(FNAME, chomp:true) do |line|
    if line.strip == section
      section_found = true
    elsif section_found
      return line[rkey_get] if line.match?(rkey_match)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

```
extract('[Test]', 'key1')
  #=> "value"
extract('[Test2]', 'key3')
  #=> "value4 value5"
extract('[Test]', 'key7')
  #=> nil
extract('[Test3]', 'key1')
  #=> nil
```

For

```
section = "[Test2]"
key = "key3"
```

the regular expression are computed as follows.

```
rkey_match = /\A *#{key} *= /
  #=> /\A *cat *= / 
rkey_get   = /\A *#{key} *= *\K.*/
  #=> /\A *cat *= *\K.*/
```

In `rkey_get`, `\K` loosely means to forget everything matched so far.

Depending on requirements some adustments may be needed in the construction of the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ?

```
require 'FileUtils'

section = ARGV[0]
v_key = ARGV[1]

section_found = "n"
f = File.open("myinputfile.txt", "r")

f.each_line do |line|
    if line.include? section
        section_found = 'y'
    end
    if section_found == 'y'
        if line.include? v_key
            puts "\nValues for #{section} - #{v_key} :::::::::"
            puts(line.split('=')[1])
            break  # Necessary to prevent reading same keys from subsequent sections
        end
    end
end

f.close()
```

#### Output

```
$ ruby line_after_string_match.rb Test key1

Values for Test - key1 :::::::::
 value


$ ruby line_after_string_match.rb Test2 key3

Values for Test2 - key3 :::::::::
 value4 value5
```

Comment: if line.include? section: can I double-check that it is a section starting with [ and ends with ]?

Comment: Just change the input in the command line when executingthe script :         ruby line_after_string_match.rb `[Test]` key1